# HTML SQL query issues

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I am practicing around with having a back-end database on my fake website. So far I have a user login via the login page which, if correct, will direct them to the accounts page. I am trying to get the users firstname and welcome them to the page. The page loads correctly but the sql query appears on top as some text and fname just comes out as fName not the actual firstname. The query is correct and the `sessionScope.customerNumber` is correct. I think I'm just implementing it incorrectly.

```
<sql:query var="fName">
    SELECT firstname FROM Customer WHERE customerNumber == '${sessionScope.customerNumber}';
</sql:query>

<p id ="text"> Welcome <c:out value="${fName}"/> </p>
```

Comment: You probably won't find too much help with this one. It's bad practice to include sql in your jsp / html

Comment: I get this a lot but is there  a guide on how it should be? Where should all my SQL statements go?

Comment: there are multiple patterns you could follow, but they all have one thing in common: separation.  it's easier to maintain and debug whenever you separate the code into modules.  JSP queries typically go into java files, and JSPs just contain view information

Comment: Have you heard of the MVC architecture? that's a very common one.. If I were you, I'd start there and fall into the rabbit hole.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I can't help with the code you posted, it looks correct to me.

Comment: I got it all working in the end. Was me not importing the prefix sql so the page didn't know what it was doing. I have separated my style and my JSP login just having issue in putting the SQL queries somewhere and how to make all the variables session available. Getting there slowly but surely.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47695/discussion-between-softey-and-dev-feed)